# Yii createUrl when inluding special characters

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with Yii's creating a URL when including special characters particularly with the hashtag and the dash (# -).

I noticed that when i include the # or - it removes the localization directory to the back of the URL. However if I get rid of the # or - the localization directory is in the correct location of the URL for example:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('/teamgoal/detail/'.$comment->comment->goal_id."#gallery-".$comment->comment->gc_id."");?>
```

The URL produces:

http://example.com/mtd/htdocs/teamgoal/11996#gallery-18074/language/th

which is incorrect. what I want is:

http://example.com/mtd/htdocs/th/teamgoal/detail/11996#gallery-19804

How can I solve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a rewrite rule in your configuration a following way;

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=> false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<language:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=> '<language>/<controller>/<action>/<id>',
    ),
),
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that working, the 'language/th' is still there :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have this in you create url command

... createUrl('/teamgoal/detail/' ....
the url wil contain ..../teamgoal/detail/.....

Are you sure you didn't copy something wrong? Otherwise please check if you have any special urlManager rewriting classes or rules